# Url PUSH Issue in $_POST Method

Tags: php, post, sms, sms-gateway

Currently i have been working on a project which connects to a smsgateway. Once the user sends  sms to gateway it redirects the requests to our server. Problem is they are received in $_GET method. But the sms provider says they are passing it in $_POST method. Url received at our end looks like the following.

http://www.example.com/smstest?msg=sample&id=55788

Is it possible to receive parameters in url when you use the $_POST method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one verb [(POST, GET, PUT, ...)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) when doing an [HTTP Request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol). However, you can do

```
<form name="y" method="post" action"y.php?foo=bar">
```

and then PHP will populate $_GET['foo'] as well, although the Request was POST'ed.

**For comment**

By using

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
```

Comment: Ok when i use $_GET or $_REQUEST parameters are recieved correctly. But when i use $_POST. So how can i guarantee that the request is post.

Comment: Ok thats works. The request is POST but they are sending data in url. Is it secure to send sensitive information in this method.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373016/php-passing-data-from-a-site-to-another-site-securely

Comment: @Rupesh That discussion is pretty unrelated. As far as I understand the situation it doesn't make any difference security-wise.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. The first line of every HTTP request contains the [method](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) (or verb) and the URI for which the request is made. No special restrictions are placed on the URI based on the choice of method, so POST requests may be made for a URI that includes a [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

From PHP you can access the parameters in the query string normally through `$_GET` and `$_REQUEST`. Parameters passed as part of a submitted form are accessible as always through `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: Ok when i use $_GET or $_REQUEST parameters are recieved correctly. But when i use $_POST. So how can i guarantee that the request is post.

Answer (score 2):

An HTTP request can use the *HTTP method* `POST` and still use a URL that contains query parameters. `POST` is just a "verb" used in the HTTP header, the same as `GET` (and `PUT` and `DELETE`). A URL can always contain query parameters and it can also always contain a request body (though `GET` requests *shouldn't*). The PHP variable `$_GET` simply represents the parsed URL query parameters, the variable `$_POST` simply represents the parsed request body. They do not actually have anything to do with the HTTP verb and are therefore somewhat misnamed.

Comment: Ok when i use $_GET or $_REQUEST parameters are recieved correctly. But when i use $_POST. So how can i guarantee that the request is post.

Comment: @Rak Again, the use of the `$_GET` or `$_POST` variables has *nothing* to do with the type of the request. If your gateway is sending the variables you're interested in as URL query parameters, use  `$_GET`, regardless of what type the HTTP request is. If the gateway is not sending a body in the POST request, so be it, then don't use `$_POST`.

Comment: The request is POST but they are sending data in url. Is it secure to send sensitive information in this method.

Comment: @Rak It's not any more or less secure. If anybody can intercept the request, they can read the URL and the body equally easily. It may be slightly *strange* to send a POST request without using the request body for data, but it doesn't really make a difference in this case.